# Windows task scheduler email notification?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

I am using the Windows Task Scheduler to run a executable that returns 0 when it runs successfully.  However, I would like an email notification if (1)the task fails to run or (2)the return code if anything other than 0.

Is this something the Windows Task Scheduler on Windows Server 2003 can do???

Answer (score 5):

In my quest to eradicate cmd.exe [grin], here's a Powershell script that should also work for you:

```
# attempt to run your exe.  iex is an alias for the invoke-expression cmd
iex c:\path_to_exe\myprog.exe

# $? lets us know if the previous command was successful or not
# $LASTEXITCODE gives us the exit code of the last Win32 exe execution
if (!$? -OR $LASTEXITCODE -gt 0) 
{
    $smtpServer = "smtp.mydomain.com"
    $fromAddress = "sender@mydomain.com"
    $toAddress = "recipient@mydomain.com"
    $subject = "FAIL"
    $msgBody = "HEY, YOU GOT PROBLEMS"

    # This block is optional depending on your SMTP server config
    # You need it if your SMTP server requires authentication
    $senderCreds = new-object System.Net.networkCredential
    $senderCreds.UserName = "senderusername"
    $senderCreds.Password = "senderpwd"

    $smtpClient = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
    $smtpClient.Credentials = $senderCreds
    $smtpClient.Send($fromAddress,$toAddress,$subject,$msgBody)
}
```

Comment: Do you really see that as a substitute for a simple one liner in a batch file?

Comment: Yes, as I don't have to also keep a copy of blat or some other mailer around.

Comment: Avoiding BLAT is awesome for me. Cheers for this.

Answer (score 3):

One very easy trick would be to wrap the command in a CMD / batch script and use the errorlevel returned and [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) to send email conditionally.

Comment: That's what I have always done in the past when I needed to send error messages about scheduled tasks.

Comment: +1 because that's what I have always done, until Powershell came about :)

Comment: +1 I've also always done it that way. After seeing the Powershell example I'm not about to change.

Comment: Powershell doesnt require BLAT or additional resources for me, so it's actually better.